# Please recommend best practice for integrating apache lucene with a MVC/spring web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, lucene

I've been working on a web application using Spring/MVC which is coming along nicely. We'd like to now integrate apache lucene to index a lot of the domain objects for a user search facility.

I'm undecided if I should create an indexing service that's registered within spring or do it the traditional servlet way and implement a `ServletContextListener` being registered in the `web.xml`. If anyone has done something similar I'd be greatly appreciative of hearing your suggestions.

We are new to all spring, spring/MVC and Lucene.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate already ?

Comment: Unfortunately we're using Progress OpenEdge and have been instructed to use the app-server, this means no RDBMS access. I would however for interests sake like to hear about how hibernate can help when using an hibernate backed domain.

Comment: Another point is that a lot of the entities the search provider needs to index aren't created by the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used hibernate an integration with Lucene already exists via [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/subprojects/search.html). Otherwise you have to index the entities yourself, cause i don't know OpenEdge.

Comment: Can't use hibernate with our current configuration. My question is referring to if I should write a servlet ContextListener registered directly in `web.xml` or if I should write a service and register it with spring instead.